# How do I display HTML in a C++ Window that works on XP through Win8?

Tags: html, c++

I'm looking for some simple code that will display HTML in a c++ window. I need it to be able to be run on any operating system (can't rely on .Net framework or Java or anything like that).

So far I've found this simple HTML drawing class: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3912/A-Simple-HTML-drawing-class

BUT, it doesn't support displaying images.

Does anyone know of some good code out there?

Comment: How about compiling it with Webkit? Not sure about its compatibility though.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Qt framework, it does everything you need: embedded WebKit view, cross-platform, network requests to fetch your HTML if needed...

Comment: This is not going to work as it is too bloated. My executable will be large like 60+MB which is not acceptable for this project. Any other suggestions?